# Как сгруппировать данные по месяцу и вывести количество уникальных значений по заданному атрибуту?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

Eсть CSV файл с двумя столбцами: `user_id`  и `started_at`. Значения `started_at` - это дата совершения покупки - раз (максимум 2) раза в месяц для одного id.

Хочу как-то сравнить `id` по месяцам. Для этого думала сделать таблицу с `id` и колонками с датами по месяцам.

Как лучше такую штуку провернуть?

Как ни пытаюсь на примитиве что-то сделать, как-то все не очень. вот вариант который у меня пока есть, но таким вариантом съедается часть данных:

```
dat.index=pd.to_datetime(dat['started_at'])
dat5=dat[:'2015-05-31']
dat6=dat['2015-06-01':'2015-06-30']
dat7=dat['2015-07-01':'2015-07-31']
dat8=dat['2015-08-01':]
dat5.index=dat5['user_id']
dat6.index=dat6['user_id']
dat7.index=dat7['user_id']
dat8.index=dat8['user_id']
data=dat6.merge(dat5, 'right', on='user_id')
data1=dat7.merge(data, 'right', on='user_id')
data2=dat8.merge(data1, 'right', on='user_id')
data2
```

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "сравнить id по месяцам"? Получить отчет, какой id в какие месяцы сколько раз делал покупки, выбрать top id, делающие покупки, или что-то другое? Не совсем понятна задача. Далее, я бы этот csv файл загрузил/импортировал в БД, и уже в ней делал выборки с помощью SQL

Comment: я тоже так изначально хотела сделать (импортировать в БД), но там у меня загвоздка тоже случилась. а про отчет - мне нужны данные по каждому id когда он делал покупки, чтобы потом понять кто в каком месяце отвалился, а кто пришел, а кто платит каждый месяц.

Comment: 1. Импортировать в БД csv Файл можно с помощью того же Excel, или любого средства по работе с СУБД (Dbeaver, DBVisualizer и т.д. в зависимости от того, в какую БД будете импортировать. Я рекомендую какую-нибудь нетяжелую бесплатную - FireBird, PostgreSQL, SQLite). 2. Все равно не понял, что вам в итоге нужно, думаю, вам надо описать, какие отчеты вы хотите получить на выходе.

Comment: я пробовала запихнуть в postgreSQL, создала таблицу, но импорт у меня все равно не получается.

Comment: насчет отчета: мне нужны данные по месяцам по новым id, тем, кто платил в прошлом месяце, тем, кто платил раньше, но не в прошлом месяце и отвал.

Comment: Импорт данных делали с помощью этого - COPY table_name FROM '[insert .csv dir here]' CSV WITH HEADER;  ?? Или каким-то инструментом? Почему не получается импорт - есть ошибки, или просто пустые таблицы?

Comment: ошибка невозможно открыть файл 'SQL state: 42501'

Comment: А в чем сложность с импортом в БД?! Задайте вопрос в котором опишите проблему импорта. Можно построить большой список из словарей со структурой [{id: date},...] а потом обрабатывать их в цикле, но лучше взять тот же SQLAlchemy используя SQLite (create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")) - импортировать во временную БД данные и обработать их там.

Comment: @KatiaNahornaya можете указать точно, какую команду использовали для импорта (пароли и IP адреса можете затереть)? А также убедиться, что пути к файлам прописаны корректно и есть полномочия на чтения этих файлов.

Comment: В общем, с помощью инструмента HeideSQL (www.heidisql.com/download.php?download=portable) у меня получилось создать таблицы, импортировать файлы CSV. Рекомендую использовать сторонние визуальные инструменты, если у вас не стоит задача использовать ИМЕННО Python для работы с данными.

Comment: в pgadmin 4 пробовала и через COPY table_name FROM '[insert .csv dir here]' CSV WITH HEADER; и через импорт таблицы. пусто

Answer (score 4):

Предположим у нас есть след. DataFrame:

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
    id started_at
0    1 2015-01-22
1    1 2016-01-01
2    1 2016-01-09
3    2 2016-01-11
4    3 2016-01-30
5    1 2016-02-02
6    2 2016-02-03
7    3 2016-03-03
8    1 2016-03-01
9    1 2016-03-03
10   3 2016-04-04
```

Воспользуемся методом [pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) для того чтобы подсчитать количество покупок для каждого покупателя (`id`) за месяц и преобразовать значение месяца в наименование столбцов (`pivot`) для лучшей наглядности:

```
In [6]: (df.assign(mon=df.started_at.dt.to_period('M'))
   ...:    .pivot_table(index='id', columns='mon', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
   ...:    .reset_index()
   ...:    .rename_axis(None, 1)
   ...: )
   ...:
Out[6]:
   id  2015-01  2016-01  2016-02  2016-03  2016-04
0   1        1        2        1        2        0
1   2        0        1        1        0        0
2   3        0        1        0        1        1
```

Метод [DataFrame.assign()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) создает новый виртуальный столбец